# How to set two date pickers in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am making an app by following this tutorial - [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMZaahsLyiI)
my question is how to add two date pickers for two different buttons? in my case for eg: one for Start date and one for End Date.

Code update - (initialize variables)

```
    private System.Boolean sd;
    private System.Boolean ed;
    private const int Start_Date = 1;
    private int SDYear = 2018, SDMonth = 1, SDDay = 1;
    private const int End_Date = 2;
    private int EDYear = 2018, EDMonth = 1, EDDay = 1;
    start_date = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.id.start_date_et)
    end_date = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.id.end_date_et)

          (click events )


Start_date.Click += delegate {

                 sd = true;
                 ed = false; 
                ShowDialog(Resource.Id.start_date_et);
            };

            End_date.Click += delegate {

                 ed = true;
                 sd = false;
                ShowDialog(Resource.Id.end_date_et);
            };
```

(override methods for dialog)

```
 protected override Dialog OnCreateDialog(int id)
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case (Resource.Id.start_date_et):
                    {
                        return new DatePickerDialog(this, Resource.Style.DialogTheme, this, SDYear, SDMonth, SDDay);
                        break;
                    }

                case (Resource.Id.end_date_et):
                    {
                        return new DatePickerDialog(this, Resource.Style.DialogTheme, this, EDYear, EDMonth, EDDay);
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return null;

        }
```

(ondataset interface)

```
 public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
        {
          if(sd == true){
            this.SDYear = year;
            this.SDMonth = month;
            this.SDDay = dayOfMonth;
            start_date_text = (SDMonth + 1).ToString() + "-" + SDDay.ToString() + "-" + SDYear.ToString();
            Toast.MakeText(this, (SDMonth + 1)
                + "-" + (SDDay) + "-" + SDYear, ToastLength.Short).Show();
           }else if(ed == true){


            this.EDYear = year;
            this.EDMonth = month;
            this.EDDay = dayOfMonth;
            end_date_text = (EDMonth + 1).ToString() + "-" + EDDay.ToString() + "-" + EDYear.ToString();
            Toast.MakeText(this, (EDMonth + 1)
                + "-" + (EDDay) + "-" + EDYear, ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

}

```
        }
```

I want to go by this method but whenever i try to show the start_date_text and end_date_text on a textview, either start_date_text or end_date_text shows up but not both.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: I tried creating two override methods for each Start date and End date but whenever i try to print it on a textview it is showing either Start date or End date but not both.

Comment: please SHOW US what you are actually doing.  Post the relevant parts of your code and explain exactly what bits are giving you trouble.

Comment: I updated the code please have a look

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated! i am really stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OnDateSet Method you are assigning both text value with date without putting any condition, you should check with **id** which button is clicked and based on that id you should update you StartDate TextView and EndDate TextView.

```
public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
          {          

   if(StartDateIdClicked){
        this.SDYear = year;
        this.SDMonth = month;
        this.SDDay = dayOfMonth;
        start_date_text = (SDMonth + 1).ToString() + "-" + SDDay.ToString() + "-" + SDYear.ToString();
        Toast.MakeText(this, (SDMonth + 1)
            + "-" + (SDDay) + "-" + SDYear, ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

}

```
    elseif(EndDateIdClicked){
        this.EDYear = year;
        this.EDMonth = month;
        this.EDDay = dayOfMonth;
        end_date_text = (EDMonth + 1).ToString() + "-" + EDDay.ToString() +"-" + EDYear.ToString();
        Toast.MakeText(this, (EDMonth + 1)
            + "-" + (EDDay) + "-" + EDYear, ToastLength.Short).Show();
     }
   }
```

And You are assigning **same value** for **End_Date=1** and **Start_Date=1**,when you are calling ShowDialog(Start_Date); and ShowDialog(End_Date);
then both OnCreateDialog(), switch case will be true for 
 Start_Date and End_Date

Comment: How should i add ID here for StartDate and EndDate?

Comment: Start_date.Click += delegate {
                    ShowDialog(Resource.id.startDateTxtView);
            };

            End_date.Click += delegate {
                ShowDialog(Resource.Id.endDateTxtView);
            };
Here startDateTxtView and endDateTxtView is the id which you given inside axml file.

Comment: I updated the code as per your suggestion please have a look. Now what should i put inside If() and if else() statements? if i put resource.Id.start_date_et there then it shows an error

Comment: take two boolean variable and on click of buttons put boolean variabl true and other one false and on other button click put vice versa for boolean variable and check boolean variable in if condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your cs code for date picker

```
var fragView = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.yourView, null);
        dateselect = fragView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtdeliverydateselect);

dateselect.Click += delegate
        {
            DateTime currentdate;
            currentdate = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
var dialog = new DatePickerDialogFragment(Activity, currentdate, this);
            dialog.Show(FragmentManager, "date");
        };
```

your axml code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtdeliverydateselect"
                android:hint="Monday 31 October"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                 android:textSize="18dp"
                />
</LinearLayout>
```

User the same of other date picker

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I have updated the code, i want to go by that method as it is more suitable for my project. Could you please take a look?

Comment: what is Resource.Layout.yourView here?

Comment: .yourview is your view in which you need picker